# same UI but different data generated dynamically

Tags: android

i am creating a list view in android application which displays  the student names and i want that on click of each item on list view it displays a student form including fields like:-name,class,roll no etc.On every click the layout of student form remain same but data changes dynamically according to Student name clicked . i have the data of students stored and i am creating a single layout for student form  and i am not getting how to set the value of fields in student form accordingly item selected.

Comment: Are you navigating to next activity after click of list item ???

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you using `ListView` or something? we can help you further if you improve your question, please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Good guy @nandsito